# Count uniq instances of blocks of 2 lines

Tags: uniq

Given input:

```
144.252.36.69
afrloop=32235330165603
144.252.36.69
afrloop=32235330165603
144.252.36.69
afrloop=32235330165603
222.252.36.69
afrloop=31135330165603
222.252.36.69
afrloop=31135330165603
222.252.36.69
afrloop=31135330165603
222.252.36.69
afrloop=31135330165603
```

How can I output:

```
144.252.36.69
afrloop=32235330165603 3 times
222.252.36.69
afrloop=31135330165603 4 times
```

Comment: [PSA: Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/135943)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
paste - - < file | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Nice! Took  me a little while to understand what paste does in this case :-)

Comment: @NickD yes, not very easy to understand. Paste takes multiple files as input and each of them can be prepaced with `-` which is signal to read from stdin. So here we read from stdin twice.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `awk` if you want a customized output format

```
NR%2==1 {ip=$0; next}
NR%2==0 {a[ip"\n"$0]++}
END {
    for(i in a)
        printf "%s %d times\n", i, a[i]
}
```

the script can be executed as

```
awk -f main.awk file
```

**Explanation**

- First, we use `NR%2==1` to match for odd number lines since odd number modulo 2 equals 1, if any line matches this condition then we save the whole line `$0` into a variable called `ip`. We can use `next` to skip any further processing and go straight to the next iteration.
- Second, we use `NR%2==0` to match even number lines, if a line matches then we create an index labeled as `ip"\n"$0` in an array `a` and increment the count value of that specific index. For example, an equivalent expansion would be like

  ```
  a["144.252.36.69 afrloop=32235330165603"] += 1
  ```

  I ignored the new line `\n` in this example just for simplicity
- Finally at `END`, after each line has been processed, we use a `for` loop to print out the value of each element inside array `a` which in our case is the count number for each unique index

**Fun Benchmark**

- Test file generation (1 million records)

  ```
  awk '
      BEGIN{for(i=1;i<10000000;i++)
      printf "%d\nafrLoop=%d\n", int(rand()*100), int(rand()*10)}
  ' > test

  $ head test
  23
  afrLoop=2
  84
  afrLoop=1
  58
  ```
- @n.caillou paste solution

  ```
  $ time paste - - < test | sort | uniq -c > /dev/null
  real    0m11.250s
  user    0m11.352s
  sys     0m0.272s
  ```
- awk solution

  ```
  $ time awk -f main.awk test > /dev/null
  real    0m5.673s
  user    0m5.636s
  sys     0m0.036s
  ```

Comment: i have log file 1,4G :v when i use awk :v it'll take so long time :D but tks u

Comment: @ĐặngThắng Thanks for the feedback! It seems a bit strange to me that you would find the awk solution to be slower. From experience, it should be faster since it doesn't go through any additional pipes. I added a benchmark section to my original answer in case you want to try it out :)

Comment: can u explain for me with ur script of u. ..tks

Comment: @ĐặngThắng Sure, glad to. Just updated the answer. Let me know if there is still anything unclear to you.

Comment: much more elegant than my `awk '!(NR%2){print$0" " p}{p=$0}' | uniq -c | awk '{print $3"\n"$2" "$1" times"}'`

Comment: @TimKennedy Thanks for the alternative solution, I found your condition statement to be more concise.